# Kubernetes services not accessible outside

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I've developed a simple app composed of two services: result and voting. You can find all the files [here](https://github.com/raul-parada/voting-app/tree/main). The services are configured as loadbalancer and the minikube tunnel recognize them. However, I cannot access the service from another machine in the same WiFi network. I've disable the firewall in the host machine (Ubuntu). I don't know if it is possible and how to do it. Thanks!

The output of the kubectl get services is:

```
NAME             TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP     PORT(S)        AGE
db               ClusterIP      10.97.110.57     <none>          5432/TCP       5d6h
kubernetes       ClusterIP      10.96.0.1        <none>          443/TCP        7d3h
redis            ClusterIP      10.101.153.119   <none>          6379/TCP       5d6h
result-service   LoadBalancer   10.110.1.59      10.110.1.59     80:30005/TCP   5d6h
voting-service   LoadBalancer   10.104.170.27    10.104.170.27   80:30004/TCP   5d6h
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the information at hand, there are many points to consider on why you are having issues accessing the service inside the same WIFI network. The first thing that you need to validate is if the service is exposed correctly. Run ‘kubectl get services’ and check if External IP addresses are assigned and try pinging from another machine to see if it's successful. Also if you get any error messages that would be much easier to diagnose where the issue is coming from. Hope this helps.[1]

[1] https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/

Comment: Thanks @ray-john-navarro! I've updated the Q with the output. The WiFi network provides the regular private ip 192.168.1.X however, when I run minikube start, this new interface receives the IP 192.168.59.100 with GW .1. When running minikube tunnel I get this output: route: 10.96.0.0/12 -> 192.168.59.100 minikube: Running. And as observed in the Q, the services provide external IPs unreachable from outside. I can ping from one machine to another to the 192.168.1.X addresses but the rest. I don't know if I'm missing some routing rules.